# Unable to use JSON data with Newtonsoft.Json in WPF

Tags: c#, json, wpf, json.net, office365api

I am retrieving data from office365 api. The response is in JSON format. I want to get data like Id, DisplayName etc. into variables but not getting the right way to do it. Following [this link](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm). I'm new to API and JSON. Will Appreciate pointers as well towards best learning links.Sample JSON below for listing sub folders of Inbox folder.

**Response JSON data.**

```
{"@odata.context":"https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/$metadata#Me/Folders('Inbox')/ChildFolders","value":
[
{"@odata.id":"https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/Users('sample.user@demosite.com')/Folders('AAMkADBjMGZiZGFlLTE4ZmEtNGRlOS1iMjllLTJmsdfsdfdDSFSDFDFDF=')",
"Id":"AAMkADBjMdfgdfgDFGDFGDFGdfGDFGDFGDFGGDzrACAAB4xqMmAAA=",
"DisplayName":"SampleFolder","ParentFolderId":"AAMkADBjMGZiZGFlLTE4ZmEtNGRlOS1sdsDFSDFSDFSDFSDFSDFDFDFrACAAAAAAEMAAA=","ChildFolderCount":0,"UnreadItemCount":8,"TotalItemCount":94},
{"@odata.id":"https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/Users('sample.user@demosite.com')/Folders('AAMkADBjMGZiZGFlLTE4ZmEasdasdasdASDASDASDASDSADDASDASDAB4xqMnAAA=')",
"Id":"AAMkADBjMGZiZGFlLTE4ZmEtNGRlOS1iMjllLTJmOGZkNGRhZmIzNQAuAasdASDASDASDASEDASDASDxSEHjzrACAAB4xqMnAAA=",
"DisplayName":"AnotherSampleFolder","ParentFolderId":"AAMkADBjMGZiZGFlLTE4ZmEtNGRlOS1sdsDFSDFSDFSDFSDFSDFDFDFrACAAAAAAEMAAA=","ChildFolderCount":0,"UnreadItemCount":21,"TotalItemCount":75}
]
}
```

The **C# code** using to parse JSON and find the required data.

```
HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.SendAsync(request).Result;

if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
  throw new WebException(response.StatusCode.ToString() + ": " + response.ReasonPhrase);

 string content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
 JObject jResult = JObject.Parse(content);


if (jResult["odata.error"] != null)
                throw new Exception((string)jResult["odata.error"]["message"]["value"]);
//Attempt one - using dynamic  [NOT WORKING - getting NULL values in the variables]         
dynamic results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(content);
var folderName = results.Id;
var folderId = results.Name;
//Attempt two - [Not working - Throwing exception - 
//Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
var folderID = (string)jResult["odata.context"]["odata.id"][0]["Id"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a class for your json object

```
public class RootObject
 {
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "@odata.context")]
    public string context { get; set; }
    public List<Value> value { get; set; }
 }

public class Value
 {
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "@odata.id")]
    public string dataId { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string ParentFolderId { get; set; }
    public int ChildFolderCount { get; set; }
    public int UnreadItemCount { get; set; }
    public int TotalItemCount { get; set; }

 }
```

Then Json Convert the Json string to your RootObject if your are using Newtonsoft Json then Deserilaze by using

```
RootObject shortiee = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>("Your Json String");
```

Comment: appreciate your help. I will give it a try and let you know if it's working or facing any issue.

Comment: @Ashok_karale use can this http://json2csharp.com/ to convert your json to class.

Answer (score 1):

```
private List<string> GetDisplayNames(JObject content)
{
    var obj = Json.Parse(content);
    var values = obj["value"].ToList();
    var displayNames = new List<string>();

    foreach (var value in values)
    {
        displayNames .Add(system["DisplayName"].ToString());
    }

    return displayNames;
}
```

This would return the names, for example, and you could do this for each value you need to retrieve. However, this does not require you to serialize/deserialize the json object before using it. It works, but is most likely not best practice.

```
if (jResult["odata.error"] != null)
                throw new Exception((string)jResult["odata.error"]["message"]["value"]);
//Attempt one - using dynamic  [NOT WORKING - getting NULL values in the variables]         
dynamic results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(content);
```

Side note: There is no key called "odata.error" in your JSON data. So you're effectively calling something which will return null.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that. Actually I am using the existing code which had that code. Appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to deserialise JSON is to create model classes for the objects you want to process and deserialise into them directly, eg. `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Folder>(content)`. As you are talking to an Office365 API, you find documentation and examples [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations#GetFolder) on how they are defined.

Taken your folder response as an example, your model for a single `Folder` could look like this:

```
public class Folder
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "@odata.id")]
    public string OdataId { get; set; }

    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    public string ParentFolderId { get; set; }

    public int ChildFolderCount { get; set; }

    public int UnreadItemCount { get; set; }

    public int TotalItemCount { get; set; }
}
```

Note1: in your example, you get a response with *list* of folders, so have to adjust this accordingly.
Note2: you can use `JsonProperty` to define a mapping between a JSON property/key and a C# property as shwon for `@odata.id`.

However, you can also use the [Outlook Client Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/use-outlook-rest-api#use-a-client-library-to-access-the-outlook-rest-api) which would make it mostly unnecessary to deal with JSON data directly (which seems preferable, unless you have a very specific reason to deal with JSON directly).

Comment: appreciate your help. I will give it a try and let you know the result.